# How do I combine mesh to all move together with an armature?

Tags: 3d, blender, mesh

I can't figure out how to make all these parts move together. I joined them, however, they are still separate? How do I make my model move its parts together?

[image: Joined model.]
[image: Not so joined model.]

Comment: Welcome to GameDev =) While arguments could be made on why this *is* the right place for your question, I have to ask *what does this have to do with video game development?* Your question sounds like its equally applicable to general 3D modelling, which can be used for any number of things, *including* game dev. More to the point, you might actually receive a better answer at [the Blender Stack Exchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

First: because you joined different objects that are now part of the same mesh, you have useless vertices. The fact that these vertices arent connected might create small gaps in your mesh during animation. I would suggest fixing this by either using 'remove doubles' or doing so manually in case remove doubles doesnt do the trick.

Second: weight painting should fix the problem.

1 of the many videos you can find on the subject:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MJPq4k_aU4